# Problems joining two tables properly

Tags: php, mysql

[image: MySQL tables]

I have these two tables above. The first table contains different drugs. The second table contains verified combinations of any two drugs from the first table.

By default there is a reference drug where drugID = $_GET['ref'] in the URL. Lets just say default.php?ref=3 for vaccine.

I want to list all drugs from the drugs table, except where drugID = $_GET['ref'] = 3. This will show all drugs except vaccine. This is done like this:

```
    $ref = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM drugs WHERE drugID != {$ref} ORDER BY drug ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row["drug"];

    }
}
```

For every drug in the loop (drugID) I want to check whether there exist a comboID where drugID and $_GET['ref'] are both found in either drug1_ID or drug2_ID. If such a comboID exist, echo "combination found:" . row['comboID'] . row["interaction"]. This should return 4 combinations with vaccine.

I have tried left, right, inner and full join of the tables, but nothing seems to work. How can this be done?

In the following example, I tried to left join:

```
SELECT *
FROM drugs
LEFT JOIN combination
ON (drugs.ID = combination.drug1_ID AND {$ref} = combination.drug2_ID) OR ({$ref} = combination.drug1_ID AND drugs.ID = combination.drug2_ID);
```

This just returns every drug, but more than once if combination is found.

Comment: A `JOIN` is the right way to go. Can you show the joins you've attempted?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have edited my answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Dharman thank you for the links! Very useful, I will study the problem. Steven reminded me of my stupidity, and he prepared the input for me. So all should be good now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

- You want to `SELECT` all drugs from the `drugs` table **except** for the reference drug
- You want to join the `combination` table so as to show combinations of drugs with the reference drug.

Output should look something like:

```
drugs.drugID | drugs.drug      | combination.comboID | combination.interaction
-------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------
1            | Paracetamol     | 1                   | ok
2            | Benzodiazepine  | 2                   | ok
4            | Calcium blocker | 3                   | ok
5            | Sodium blocker  | 4                   | ok
6            | Cold meds       | NULL                | NULL
7            | Pain meds       | NULL                | NULL
8            | Grape juice     | NULL                | NULL
9            | Cannabis        | NULL                | NULL
10           | Salt            | NULL                | NULL
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT drugs.drugID, drugs.drug, combination.comboID, combination.interaction
FROM drugs
    LEFT JOIN combination                                                -- Left join so we select all rows from FIRST table
        ON drugs.drugID IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)  -- Only join where drug from first table is one of the drugs in the combination
            AND ? IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)        -- Only join where the reference drug is also in the combination
WHERE drugs.drugID != ?                                                  -- Exclude reference drug from first table
```

**PHP - mysqli**

```
$reference_drug = $_GET["ref"] ?? NULL;

if($reference_drug){
    $sql = "
        SELECT drugs.drugID, drugs.drug, combination.comboID, combination.interaction
        FROM drugs
        LEFT JOIN combination 
            ON drugs.drugID IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)
                AND ? IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)
        WHERE drugs.drugID != ?
    ";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param("ii", $reference_drug, $reference_drug);
    $query->execute();
    $query->store_result();
    $query->bind_result($drug_id, $drug_name, $combination_id, $combination_status);
    while($query->fetch()){
        echo "$drug_id, $drug_name, $combination_id, $combination_status\n";
    }

}
else{
    echo "Error: No reference drug supplied.";
}
```

**PHP - PDO**

Don't forget that **any** user input should be treated as *untrusted*_ and therefore shouldn't be put directly into a query.

```
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_user = "some_user";
$db_pass = "db_password";
$db_name = "db_name";

$this->pdo = new pdo(
    "mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);

$reference_drug = $_GET["ref"] ?? NULL;

if($reference_drug){
    $sql = "
        SELECT drugs.drugID, drugs.drug, combination.comboID, combination.interaction
        FROM drugs
        LEFT JOIN combination 
            ON drugs.drugID IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)
                AND ? IN (combination.drug1_ID, combination.drug2_ID)
        WHERE drugs.drugID != ?
    ";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([$reference_drug, $reference_drug]);
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row["drugID"];
    }

}
else{
    echo "Error: No reference drug supplied.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... it's working like a charm! I can't believe this was so complicated for me. Thanks for reminding me of SQL injections, too. I'm new to PHP, so it means a lot. Did you make it "injection secure" with the "?? NULL" statement?

Comment: No problem! The `?? NULL;` just sets the value to `NULL` if the value from `$_GET` doesn't exist -- so that we can use it in the if statement. The prepared statement `$query->prepare($sql)` is what protects you from SQL injection. By using place holders `?` for values in the query the SQL server knows automatically that bound values are not part of the query!

Comment: I can't seem to be able to unbind the parameters you made. I want to do this because there's actually a lot more data than shown here (almost 50 columns). Is it possible to SELECT * and then use row["name"] as per usual?

Comment: I see. If you were using `fetch_assoc` before then presumably you have the `mysqlind` driver in use: which means you can use `$query->get_result();` instead of `->store_result()` and then `->fetch_assoc()`. However, in this case I'd probably go down the PDO route (see additional code in answer)